# How to read multiple jpg images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have 250 images stored in `in_dir = 'C:\Users\DJDJ\Desktop\pic';`

These pictures are arranged as following and named : image1 , image2, image3, ..., image250.

I want to read all these images and process them starting by image1, after processing go to process image2, and after image3 to image250

then saved the resultant images after pre-processing in a specific file, for example at `out_dir = 'C:\Users\DJDJ\Desktop\pic output';`.

How can I do this in matlab?

Comment: thank you for answering my question

Comment: the problem is reading the images as : image1 ,image2....image250 and i am trying to read them from in_dir = 'C:\Users\DJDJ\Desktop\pic' and after to save them in out_dir = 'C:\Users\DJDJ\Desktop\pic output';

Comment: for px = 1 : 250
fname=(['image',num2str(px),'.jpg']);
current_image = imread(fullfile(in_dir, fname,'jpg'));                                                                                                         
out_image = current_image ;                                                                                                                                                    imwrite(out_image, fullfile(out_dir, fname,'jpg'));
end